# Cannot deserialize instance of object out of START_ARRAY token in Spring 3 REST Webservice

Tags: android, spring, jackson

I am making use of this cool thing Spring offers: Spring RESTWebService (Version of spring is 3). If I access the URL from browser I can see the JSON response, but from a Client endpoint (Android application) iIreceive this error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: 
    I/O error: Can not deserialize instance of MyObject out of START_ARRAY token
  at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@4076e940; line: 1, 
    column: 1]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
    Can not deserialize instance of MyObject  out of START_ARRAY token
  at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@4076e940; line: 1, column: 1]
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:466)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:414)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:234)
   at com.be.android.locateconsultants.resources.AsyncTaskRESTServiceCaller.doInBackground(AsyncTaskRESTServiceCaller.java:43)
   at com.be.android.locateconsultants.resources.AsyncTaskRESTServiceCaller.doInBackground(AsyncTaskRESTServiceCaller.java:1)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
   ... 4 more

 Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize 
    instance of MyObject  out of START_ARRAY token
  at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@4076e940; line: 1, column: 1]
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:198)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeUsingCreator(BeanDeserializer.java:565)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:365)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2395)
   at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1655)
   at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:135)
   at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:154)
   at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:74)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:632)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:618)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:459)
   ... 10 more
```

MyObject structure is the same as the one from the server side application.

I have tried to request the server like this:

```
final String url = ".....";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Consultant> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(
            url, Consultant.class);
```

Or like this:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
ResponseEntity<MyObject> response = restTemplate
            .exchange("....",HttpMethod.GET, entity, MyObject.class);
System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + response.getBody());
```

But still the same error as above.
Can't figure out what I am missing at this point, any idea or hints would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the json structure, how MyObject looks. Not enough information. The only guess I see is that you're getting array from server and trying to map it to MyObject.

Comment: in the client:                                                   `public class Consultant {
 private int id;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String phoneNumber;
 private String jobName;
 private String workAddress;
 private Date created;
 private String email;                                    getters and setters } `

Comment: and the response json is this: `[{"id":1,"firstName":"first name","lastName":"last name","jobName":"programmer","created":1328133600000,"email":"test@yahoo.com","workAddress":"test","phoneNumber":"0000"},{...},{..}]`

Comment: Yes, then you should map it to List<Consultant> rather than to Consultant.class.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you. If you don't write the last comment as an answer I cannot tag your response as the correct one :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solution in a similar situation was to map to `Consultant[].class`
This applies if you try to deserialize a JSON array of your mapped objects.

Answer (score 23):

You should map it to `List<Consultant>` rather than to `Consultant.class`.

Comment: The tip helped me in my case also

Comment: Could you clarify this? I get syntax error when I try List<MyObject>, instead I had to use MyObject[].class

Comment: getting syntex error in this rest.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/RestCRUDWithoutDao/country/allCountries", List<Country>);

Answer (score 9):

This is related to Jackson and the way you're attempting to deserialize and initialize a container from an array.

While my usage context is a bit different, this may help some who get here from searching for Jackson-specific deserialization errors.

I had to do it like this:

```
List<Consultant> consultants = Arrays.asList(
    mapper.readValue(myJson.toString(), Consultants[].class)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

a file foo.json contains a batch of data like this:

> [{"A":"TYMH","B":"datab","C":"DLJQ","D":"datad"},
>       {"A":"TYMH","B":"datab","C":"DLJQ","D":"datad"}]

The following statement gives you an ArrayList of LinkedHashMap, where A B C D are the keys.

```
List list = mapper.readValue(new File("D:\\...\\foo.json"), List.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize an array from a json like:

```json
[
  {"foo":"bar"}, {"foo1":"bar1"}
]
```

You must configure the value deserializer to accept an array in the method signature.

```java
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, DTO[]> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
                groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG, true);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props,
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(DTO[].class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, DTO[]>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, DTO[]> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

And in your consumer:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "foo-topic", groupId = "foo-group")
void listen(DTO[] dtos) {

}
```

No type reference or other things needed. I think underneath, `ObjectArrayDeserializer` is used.

Note that in this way, you will need to put all configs into java code, and (maybe) all configs by YAML will not work for consumer. I am not sure but you can try to combine code config and YAML config.