# Issue with parsing the content from JSON file with Jackson & message- JsonMappingException -Cannot deserialize as out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

Given the following .json file:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "New York",
        "number" : "732921",
        "center" : [
                "latitude" : 38.895111, 
                "longitude" : -77.036667
            ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "San Francisco",
        "number" : "298732",
        "center" : [
                "latitude" : 37.783333, 
                "longitude" : -122.416667
            ]
    }
]
```

I prepared two classes to represent the contained data:

```
public class Location {
    public String name;
    public int number;
    public GeoPoint center;
}
```

...

```
public class GeoPoint {
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
}
```

In order to parse the content from the .json file I use [Jackson 2.2.x](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) and prepared the following method:

```
public static List<Location> getLocations(InputStream inputStream) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
        CollectionType collectionType = typeFactory.constructCollectionType(
                                            List.class, Location.class);
        return objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, collectionType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

As long as I leave out the `center` property all content can be parsed. However, when I try to parse the geo-coordinates I end up with the following error message:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of
>     com.example.GeoPoint out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@416a5850; line: 5, column: 25]
>   (through reference chain: com.example.Location["center"])

Comment: why are you using jackson  if you can simply parse it with json parser

Comment: Your JSON string is malformed, the type of `center` is an array of invalid objects. Try to replace `[` and `]` with `{` and `}` in the JSON string around `longitude` and `latitude` so they will be objects.

Comment: @Katona Thank you. Can you please convert your comment into an answer so I can close the question?!

Comment: I had the same error, but because I had used a LocalDate class. Once i added the missing JavaTimeModule with "mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());" , the problem went away.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Your JSON string is malformed: the type of `center` is an array of invalid objects. Replace `[` and `]` with `{` and `}` in the JSON string around `longitude` and `latitude` so they will be objects:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "New York",
        "number" : "732921",
        "center" : {
                "latitude" : 38.895111, 
                "longitude" : -77.036667
            }
    },
    {
        "name" : "San Francisco",
        "number" : "298732",
        "center" : {
                "latitude" : 37.783333, 
                "longitude" : -122.416667
            }
    }
]
```

Comment: The same problem I had, but it crazy since in jackson 2.6.3v there was a totally different crazy error, and with 2.9.8v everything worked. Damn it, so these serialization errors are so annoying.

Comment: Atul Sharma answer Below looks more relevant for this question. Kindly review and modify. Thanks

Answer (score 191):

`JsonMappingException: out of START_ARRAY token` exception is thrown by Jackson object mapper as it's expecting an `Object {}` whereas it found an `Array [{}]` in response.

This can be solved by replacing `Object` with `Object[]` in the argument for `geForObject("url",Object[].class)`. 
References:

1. [Ref.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26796142/452708)
2. [Ref.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28449667/452708)
3. [Ref.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25512128/452708)

Comment: For Kotliners here is an example: val result: ResponseEntity<Array<BillingType>> = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Array<BillingType>::class.java)

Answer (score 20):

I sorted this problem as verifying the json from JSONLint.com and then, correcting it. And this is code for the same.

```
String jsonStr = "[{\r\n" + "\"name\":\"New York\",\r\n" + "\"number\": \"732921\",\r\n"+ "\"center\": {\r\n" + "\"latitude\": 38.895111,\r\n"  + " \"longitude\": -77.036667\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "},\r\n" + " {\r\n"+ "\"name\": \"San Francisco\",\r\n" +\"number\":\"298732\",\r\n"+ "\"center\": {\r\n" + "    \"latitude\": 37.783333,\r\n"+ "\"longitude\": -122.416667\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "]";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo[] jsonObj = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, MyPojo[].class);

for (MyPojo itr : jsonObj) {
    System.out.println("Val of name is: " + itr.getName());
    System.out.println("Val of number is: " + itr.getNumber());
    System.out.println("Val of latitude is: " + 
        itr.getCenter().getLatitude());
    System.out.println("Val of longitude is: " + 
        itr.getCenter().getLongitude() + "\n");
}
```

Note: `MyPojo[].class` is the class having getter and setter of json properties.

Result:

```
Val of name is: New York
Val of number is: 732921
Val of latitude is: 38.895111
Val of longitude is: -77.036667
Val of name is: San Francisco
Val of number is: 298732
Val of latitude is: 37.783333
Val of longitude is: -122.416667
```

Comment: This fixed the problem I've been having for days, no other answers made sense.
For anyone else having the same error. It's worth noting that if your JSON has multiple object in, you need to be returning multiple objects. I had been returning MyObject, where I should have been returning MyObject[]

Answer (score 16):

As said, `JsonMappingException: out of START_ARRAY token` exception is thrown by Jackson object mapper as it's expecting an `Object {}` whereas it found an `Array [{}]` in response.

A simpler solution could be replacing the method `getLocations` with:

```
public static List<Location> getLocations(InputStream inputStream) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        TypeReference<List<Location>> typeReference = new TypeReference<>() {};
        return objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, typeReference);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't have a pojo like `Location`, you could use:

```
TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>> typeReference = new TypeReference<>() {};
return objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, typeReference);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this alternative implementation. Can you tell if there are advantages or disadvantages with using `CollectionType` vs. `TypeReference`?

Comment: `TypeReference` syntax is far shorter than the other. Not sure, if in some cases there could be a counter-indication related to the type erasure... but in my world `TypeReference` is just easier to use and understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with web services, the problem could be in the body value. You could send the value with an array in the following way

[image]

And obtain the error

[image]

To fix it, you must change the body correctly as an object

[image]

Greetings

Answer (score -1):

For instance:

data class

```
data class ToDo(
var id: Int, 
var text: String?, 
var completed: Boolean?) {}
```

Above deserialization error thrown when you use ToDo::class.java but not Array::class.java for json list

**DOEST NOT WORK**

```
    private val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
    .....
    val todo= mapper.readValue(response.body(), ToDo::class.java)
```

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize value of type `com.example.api.dto.ToDo` from Array value
> (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)  at [Source:
> (String)"[{"id":14,"text":"TEST","completed":true},{"id":13,"text":"TEST","completed":true},{"id":19,"text":"TEST","completed":true"[truncated
> 84 chars]; line: 1, column: 1]

**WORK**

```
private val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
.....
val todos = mapper.readValue(response.body(), Array<ToDo>::class.java)
```