# Jackson unable to map JSON to an Object containing a Map

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, linkedhashmap

I have a Java POJO like so:

```
public class Widget {
    private Map<String,Object> params;

    // Getter, setter, ctor, etc...
}
```

I have a method that currently receives a JSON `String`, and is attempting to use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to map that JSON into a `Widget` instance:

```
public Widget fromJSON(String json) {
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return jsonMapper.readValue(json, Widget.class);
}
```

Currently the JSON I'm passing in is:

```
{
    "params": [{
        "acks": "all"
    }, {
        "retries": 0
    }, {
        "batch.size": 16384
    }, {
        "linger.ms": 1
    }, {
        "buffer.memory": 33554432
    }, {
        "key.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
    }, {
        "value.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
    }]
}
```

When this runs I get the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance
    of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
```

I see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19333106/4009451) addressing a very similar problem, except that question addresses using Jackson to map JSON to a Java `Map`, not an object (`Widget`) that *contains* a Java `Map`.

I've used http://jsonlint.com to verify that the JSON is valid. **So I either need to change the JSON or the code, or possibly both.** Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON is valid, but not for a Map. The value of `params` is an array, it should be an object like:

```
{
    "params": {
        "acks": "all",
        "retries": 0,
        "batch.size": 16384,
        "linger.ms": 1,
        "buffer.memory": 33554432,
        "key.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
        "value.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
    }
}
```

At [Jackson Five Minutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) you can find the following relation:

> Concrete Java types that Jackson will use for simple data binding are:
>
> ```
> ╔══════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
> ║      JSON Type       ║          Java Type           ║
> ╠══════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
> ║ object               ║ LinkedHashMap<String,Object> ║
> ║ array                ║ ArrayList<Object>            ║
> ║ string               ║ String                       ║
> ║ number (no fraction) ║ Integer, Long or BigInteger  ║
> ║ number (fraction)    ║ Double (or BigDecimal)       ║
> ║ true|false           ║ Boolean                      ║
> ║ null                 ║ null                         ║
> ╚══════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A `List<Map<String, Object>>` should do the trick:

```java
public class Widget {

    private List<Map<String, Object>> params;

    // Getter and setters ommited
}
```