# ObjectMapper is not accepting JSON response from HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

Have issues while reading a `JSON` String that I am building from `BufferedReader` and trying to assign the values to POJO class.

It works when I use this format (Discovered by accident. copy paste):

`String build = {\"feature\":{\"id\":\"888888\",\"name\":\"A9 Refresh Release\"}`

But actually when reading from the `BufferedReader`, it looks like below one:-

`{"feature":{"id":"888888","name":"A9 Refresh Release"}}`

Here is my code:

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
         build.append(inputLine); }
    in.close();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Feature wrap = mapper.readValue(build, Feature.class);
```

My problem isn't that I don't know how to marshall JSON string to POJO but the JSON response which I am getting from my `HttpURLConnection` isn't valid for the `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: `{"feature":{"id":"888888","name":"A9 Refresh Release"}` is not valid `json` - try adding another `}`

Comment: Thats what I getting from response

Comment: it ain't telling you no lies

Comment: why do you think that?

Comment: Sorry I was looking at the wrong JSON

Comment: If it not JSON than how should I be building the response as a JSON String?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but not really related to json specifically,  Strings that want to contain `"` will need to escape them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the following JSON String to POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499935/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-pojo)

Comment: @Abhinav Very close but I am not building the JSON manually. Im doing a `GET` with my `HttpURLConnection`. The JSON is provided as shown in my `String`. I cant add the rest of the code since it requires authentication Key

Comment: @Tags What do you mean by  _JSON response isn't valid _? Would you mind to post that (**_invalid JSON response_**)as well as a part of your question?

Comment: What is your Feature.class ? Does it have a 'feature' property which is an object? I assume the Feature class has only id and name properties, so you need to create a wrapper class. (If your Feature.class is actually a wrapper, then ignore this comment)

Comment: @Abhinav the second JSON String I posted on my question I’m getting an error. The first JSON string I manually typed works. Obviously I want to use the JSON string I’m getting from my HTTP request but the response is the second String

Comment: @Selindek it is a wrapper class and it works. I just can’t get it to work with my HTTP request. The response is on my question.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, **you have to parse JSON string into Jackson JsonNode** first.

```
public <T> T readValue(JsonParser jp,
              Class<T> valueType)
            throws IOException,
                   JsonParseException,
                   JsonMappingException
```

*Method to deserialize JSON content into a non-container type (it can be an array type, however): typically a bean, array or a wrapper type (like Boolean).*

**Note:** this method should NOT be used if the result type is a container (Collection or Map. The reason is that due to type erasure, key and value types cannot be introspected when using this method.

Eventually, there are 2 solutions to your problem as below:-

**1. Quick Parsing:-**

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
         build.append(inputLine); }
         in.close();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Feature wrap = mapper.readValue(mapper.readTree(build), Feature.class);
```

**2. Low-Level Parsing:-**

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
         build.append(inputLine); }
         in.close();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();
    JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(build);
    Feature wrap = mapper.readValue(mapper.readTree(parser), Feature.class);
```

Comment: `mapper.readTree(build)` only accepts `JsonNode`. The `build` object is a StringBuilder. Getting this error; `The method readTree(JsonParser) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (StringBuilder)`

Comment: the `readValue` im using is: `public <T> T readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)
        throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException
    {
        return (T) _readMapAndClose(_jsonFactory.createParser(content), _typeFactory.constructType(valueType));
    } `

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. The `ObjectMapper.readValue(Sting a, valyetype)` as Stated only takes in strings. I was sending a `StringBuilder`. The `StringBuilder` wont format my JSON but a `String` will. Simple fix

```
Feature wrap = mapper.readValue(build.toString(), Feature.class);
```