# How to convert a JSON to Java object but with translated values

Tags: java

I have a JSON like below and I want to generate the Java object of the respective class by parsing it. The catch is that I don't want the value for maxtime in that object to be set as {{ Instant.MAX.toString()}}, but it should be its translated value, which means it should be +1000000000-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z. Is there any standard library to achieve this similar requirement or I will have to write a customized code for this?

```
{
  "key1": "",
  "key2": "",
  "key3": {
    "maxTime": "{{ Instant.MAX.toString()}}",
    "anotherKey": "{{MyProjectUtils.getKey()}}"
  }
}
```

In the worst case, I am ready to replace this JSON file with some other type of file but at the end, I want a java object with translated values.

Comment: Could you please share the use case behind this requirement?

Comment: have you tried freemarker https://freemarker.apache.org/?

Comment: The use case is that in our project we write almost similar code but for each type of client with a different configuration to solve their need. Now our clients are increasing and we want to make it a config only solution so that we can ship faster. So we are writing a layer on our current framework which will read configs from json and create objects required for our framework.

Comment: I didn't use freemarker, but I can try. Does it work for JSON as well?

Comment: Yes @NikunjAggarwal

Answer (score -1):

You may create a JavaBean/POJO object from a JSON file. You may adjust the members in POJO Object according to the JSON File.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499935/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-pojo) is how to create a POJO object from a JSON file.

Comment: You have explained about creating JSON from a java object but my question is about creating a java object from the JSON.

Comment: @NikunjAggarwal You are right, I misunderstood. I'll update my answer. However, the summary is: you can do the reverse conversion operation by creating a POJO object. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499935/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-pojo) is the answer to the reverse conversion operation.

Comment: Its not that simple bro. Read it again. There is a catch