# Deserialize an object with children

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Json list using object with children

```
{
 "id":"154",
 "name":"peter",
 "children": [
               {
                "id":"122",
                "name": "mick",
                "children":[]
               },
               {
                "id":"123",
                "name": "mick",
                "children":[]
               }
            ]
}
```

Here is the class of my object:

```
public class person{
                    private String id;
                    private String name;
                    private List<person> children;

//getters and setters
}
```

When I try to deserialize this object, I have the following error

> Can not deserialize instance of person out of START_ARRAY token

What should I do ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333106/jsonmappingexception-out-of-start-array-token

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your help The Json I receive is OK and cannot be changed. I might have rewritten it with some mistakes though.

Comment: @Jean then please update your question with correct JSON

Answer (score 1):

The JSON contains an array of persons.
Your class a List of `person`.

Either change the JSON like `@Naveed Yadav` suggested or change the class to

```
public class Person{
             private String id;
             private String name;
             private Person[] children;

//getters and setters
}
```

(BTW the class name should be upper case in Java)

Answer (score 1):

Fix syntax errors in your JSON body and you'll be in a good shape:

```
{
 "id":"154",
 "name":"peter",
 "children": [
               {
                "id":"122",
                "name": "mick",
                "children":[], <== Excess comma
               } <== Missing comma 
               {
                "id":"123",
                "name": "mick",
                "children":[], <== Excess comma
               }
            ]
}
```

Valid one:

```
{
    "id": "154",
    "name": "peter",
    "children": [{
            "id": "122",
            "name": "mick",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "mick",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your POJO declaration like below:-

```
 public class person{
                private String id;
                private String name;
                private List<Children> children;

               //getters and setters

   private class Children{
                private String id;
                private String name;
                private String[] children;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{
 "id":"154",
 "name":"peter",
 "children": 
               {
                "id":"122",
                "name": "mick",
                "children":[],
               }
               {
                "id":"123",
                "name": "mick",
                "children":[],
               }

}
```

Comment: or change to `private person[] children;`