# object out of START_ARRAY token in Spring resttemplate

Tags: android, spring, resttemplate

I have same problem with this one and it's great to see this with a solution already. but I cant implement it on my code.

([Cannot deserialize instance of object out of START_ARRAY token in Spring 3 REST Webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719729/cannot-deserialize-instance-of-object-out-of-start-array-token-in-spring-3-rest))

here's mine

```
MyModelClass modelClass=restTemplate.postForObject(url,mvm,MyModelClass.class);
```

based on the answer on the link a gave, I should replace MyModelClass.class by a List containing MyModelClass but I'm getting a syntax error.like this one

```
MyModelClass modelClass=restTemplate.postForObject(url,mvm,List<MymodelClass>);
```

Am I doing it wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it weeks ago, and I feel that I should post my solution here for future use.

My JSON Response structure is a list of key value pairs, so what I did is

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> map=restTemplate.porsForObject(url,mvm,List.class);
```

The JSON response was converted into a map. So it is easy now to access the data by doing this.

```
String data= (Hashmap) map.get(position).get(key);
```