# Can not deserialize instance of models.PublisheDataList out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to parse json using jackson api with the following details.
but I'm getting error.
Please find the following details for code and stacktrace.

**JSON**

```
[{"id":1001,"cyPerReffe":1200,"distPercentage":"0"},{"id":1002,"cyPerReffe":1000,"distPercentage":"10"},{"id":1003,"cyPerReffe":800,"distPercentage":"20"},{"id":1004,"cyPerReffe":750,"distPercentage":"10"},{"id":1005,"cyPerReffe":700,"distPercentage":"10"},{"id":1006,"cyPerReffe":650,"distPercentage":"10"},{"id":1007,"cyPerReffe":600,"distPercentage":"20"},{"id":1008,"cyPerReffe":300,"distPercentage":"5"},{"id":1009,"cyPerReffe":333,"distPercentage":"7"},{"id":1010,"cyPerReffe":"32","distPercentage":"8"}]
```

**Controller class**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();   mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
PublisheDataList publisheDataList = mapper.convertValue(json, PublisheDataList.class);
```

the following class is my bean class.
**PublisheData.java**

```
private Long id;
private Long cyPerReffe;
private String distPercentage;
//    with setter and getters
```

**PublisheDataList.java**

```
List<PublisheData> publisheDataList;
//with setter and getters
```

I am getting  the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not deserialize instance of models.PublisheDataList out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2502)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2468)
        at controllers.RYSController.publishReferenceYield(RYSController.java:79)
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$22$$anonfun$apply$62.apply(routes_routing.scala:318)
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$22$$anonfun$apply$62.apply(routes_routing.scala:318)
        at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$6$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:175)
        at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:355)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:50)
        at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:63)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:80)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$2.apply(JavaAction.scala:79)
        at play.libs.F$Promise$PromiseActor.onReceive(F.java:425)
        at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:502)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of models.PublisheDataList out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationCenter code hereontext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:212)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:875)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2498)
        ... 21 more
```

Comment: can use mapper.convertValue(obj.get("xyz"),  new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>() { });

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need a PublisheDataList intermediate class to deserialize to a Collection, try deserializing directly with the mapper

```
List<PublisheData> publisheDataList = mapper.convertValue(json, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, PublisheData.class));
```

Comment: Useful tip just just as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719729/cannot-deserialize-instance-of-object-out-of-start-array-token-in-spring-3-rest)